# How to build a vector where every n of 0 is 1 with operator %%?

Tags: r, vector, sequence

The code here below

```
1:nrow(mtcars) %% 4
```

provides the sequence

```
1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 0
```

What should I do to get the path?

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply wrap it in parenthesis and add an `+`:

```
+(1:nrow(mtcars) %% 4 == 0)
```

The parentheses  - `(1:nrow(mtcars) %% 4 == 0)` - creates a boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` vector, the `+` converts those values to 0 or 1.

Output

```
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
vec1 <- c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L)

as.numeric(vec1 == 0)
#>  [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

A trick with `!` and `+` for code golfing

```
> +!(1:nrow(mtcars) %% 4)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

or a similar idea with `%/%`

```
> +((m <- 1:nrow(mtcars)) %/% 4 * 4 == m)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

---

Also, you can try some bitwise operations, e.g.,

- `bitwAnd` + `bitwNot`

```
> +(bitwAnd(1:nrow(mtcars), bitwNot(3)) == m)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

- `bitwShift*` approaches

```
> +(bitwShiftL(bitwShiftR(m <- 1:nrow(mtcars), 2), 2) == m)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function that takes a numeric vector and a n variables as arguments and outputs 1 for every nth element of the vector:

```
nth_as_1 <- function(vect, n) {
    +((vect %% n)== 0)
}

nth_as_1(1:nrow(mtcars), 4)
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```